# How to use Spring JPA clearAutomatically correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I encounter an issue when I used Spring JPA. I want to write the update SQL like following:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Account as a set a.status = ?1 where a.id in (?2)")
public int updateStatus(ACCOUNT_STATUS status, List<Long> id);
```

Then I write some test to test it.

```
private List<Account> createAccounts() {

    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    Account account1 = new Account();

    account1.setCaseNumber("999123");
    account1.setAccountNbr("888123");
    account1.setCaseType(CASE_TYPE.REGULAR);
    account1.setStatus(ACCOUNT_STATUS.NOT_USED);

    accountRepository.save(account1);

    Account account2 = new Account();

    account2.setCaseNumber("999456");
    account2.setAccountNbr("888456");
    account2.setCaseType(CASE_TYPE.REGULAR);
    account2.setStatus(ACCOUNT_STATUS.NOT_USED);

    accountRepository.save(account2);

    Account account3 = new Account();

    account3.setCaseNumber("999789");
    account3.setAccountNbr("888789");
    account3.setCaseType(CASE_TYPE.DISASTER);
    account3.setStatus(ACCOUNT_STATUS.NOT_USED);

    accountRepository.save(account3);

    accounts.add(account1);
    accounts.add(account2);
    accounts.add(account3);

    return accounts;
}

@Test
public void testUpdateAccountStatus() {

    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Account> accounts = createAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        ids.add(account.getId());
    }

    int count = accountRepository.updateStatus(ACCOUNT_STATUS.USED, ids);

    Assert.assertEquals(ids.size(), count);

    for (Long id  : ids) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findOne(id);
        Assert.assertEquals(ACCOUNT_STATUS.USED, account.getStatus());
    }
}
```

The test is failed because the status not changed. But actually the update SQL works good. The Accounts status have been changed.

The test can be passed in 2 ways.
If I call accountRepository.findOne() to an existed Account in the database (here, in the test code, all Account records are inserted before test started, see createAccounts method)

Or, if I add @Modifying(clearAutomatically=false), everything looks good.

I have check document about clearAutomatically in Spring website. But I still can't understand my code behavior.

My Spring-JPA version is 1.1.0 which has changed clearAutomatically default value to true.

Is there anyone know too much about Spring JPA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the default value of this attribute has changed since you used it.

See the documentation issue they seem to still have on this: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-305